# Attachment display in Microsoft Outlook under Rich Text configuration

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, icons

The question is quite simple, but I have not been able to find a solution.

I am using Outlook 2010. When I attach a certain file to an Outlook email in Rich Format, I get the following image:

[image]

The icon is quite large, and I would like to have something smaller, specifically similar to the icons you get in Windows Explorer when you set the Layout to "Details" (whereas the icon above looks similar to those you obtain when Windows Explorer Layout is set to "Tiles" or "Large Icons"):

[image]

**Is there a way to achieve this behaviour?**

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there seems to be no such an option in Outlook client to change the display of attachments in rich text to what you want.

And because Outlook 2010 is currently out of support (please refer to: [Office 2010 end of support roadmap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/endofsupport/office-2010-end-support-roadmap)), I can't do research on Outlook 2010 client in my environment. For outlook 365, you can use "crop" to reduce the icon of attachments, which is also a convenient workaround. It is recommended that you try to use the same feature in your Outlook client to reduce the size of the attachment icon.

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.